# Using DDD and AutoMapper, how do you do work on the same aggregate root in multiple services within a single unit of work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, automapper, repository-pattern

I am trying to learn and implement domain driven design in a non-web based project.  I have a main loop that will do multiple procedures on a lot of entities in a single unit of work.  I don't want any of the changes to be persisted unless the entire loop's work is successful.  I'm using AutoMapper to convert persistence models to domain models within a repository, and my services are using the repository to retrieve data before doing work.

There are some elements of DDD that are not working well with my project and I am hoping someone can tell me what I have wrong about the whole process.

Here are the DDD ideas I'm struggling with:

- Domain services should be used when a process involves multiple aggregate roots interacting with each other
- You should pass aggregate root Ids into domain services which will then use repositories to load them
- Repositories should return domain models that it constructs from mapped persistence models (in this case I am using AutoMapper)

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var unitOfWork = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
                var aggregate1Repo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAggregate1Repository>();
                var aggregate2Repo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAggregate2Repository>();
                var aggregate3Repo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAggregate3Repository>();
                var firstService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFirstService>();
                var secondService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISecondService>();

                var aggregate1 = aggregate1Repo.Find(1); //First copy of aggregate1
                var aggregate2 = aggregate2Repo.Find(1000); 
                var aggregate3 = aggregate3Repo.Find(123); 

                aggregate1.DoSomeInternalWork();

                firstService.DoWork(aggregate1.Id,aggregate2.Id); 
                secondService.DoWork(aggregate1.Id,aggregate3.Id);

                aggregate1Repo.Update(aggregate1);
                unitOfWork.Commit();
            }
```

Aggregate1Repo:

```
public class Aggregate1Repository
{
    private readonly AppDBContext _dbContext;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public Aggregate1Repository(AppDBContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }   

    public Aggregate1 Find(int id)
    {
        return _mapper.Map<Aggregate1>(_dbContext
            .SomeDBSet.AsNoTracking()
            .Find(id));
    }
}
```

FirstService:

```
public class FirstService : IFirstService
{
    private readonly IAggregate1Repository _agg1Repo;
    private readonly IAggregate2Repository _agg2Repo;

    public FirstService(IAggregate1Repository agg1Repo, IAggregate2Repository agg2Repo)
    {
        _agg1Repo = agg1Repo;
        _agg2Repo = agg2Repo;
    }

    public void DoWork(int aggregate1Id, int aggregate2Id)
    {
        var aggregate1 = _agg1Repo.Find(aggregate1Id); //second copy of aggregate1
        var aggregate2 = _agg2Repo.Find(aggregate2Id);
        //do some calculations and modify aggregate1 in some fashion
        //I could update aggregate1 in the repository here,
        // but this copy of aggregate1 doesn't have the changes made prior to this point
    }
}
```

SecondService:

```
public class SecondService : ISecondService
{
    private readonly IAggregate1Repository _agg1Repo;
    private readonly IAggregate3Repository _agg3Repo;

    public FirstService(IAggregate1Repository agg1Repo, IAggregate3Repository agg3Repo)
    {
        _agg1Repo = agg1Repo;
        _agg3Repo = agg3Repo;
    }

    public void DoWork(int aggregate1Id, int aggregate3Id)
    {
        var aggregate1 = _agg1Repo.Find(aggregate1Id); //third copy of aggregate1
        var aggregate3 = _agg2Repo.Find(aggregate3Id);
        //do some calculations and modify aggregate1 in some fashion
        //I could update aggregate1 in the repository here,
        // but this copy of aggregate1 doesn't have the changes made prior to this point
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I'd essentially be doing work to three different copies of aggregate1 since a new object is created by AutoMapper in the repository each time I try to load it.  I could put separate calls to aggregate1Repo.Update in the two services, but I'd still be working on three different objects that all represent the same thing.  I feel like I must have a fundamental flaw in my thinking, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: As I understand aggregate1, aggregate2 and aggregate3 should be a different objects, otherwise it does not have a sence to query the same object from different repositories. Could you please provide more details?

Comment: Yes aggregate1, aggregate2, and aggregate3 would be entirely different types of objects.  They are each separate aggregate roots.  FirstService and SecondService would essentially do some sort of work that involves multiple aggregate roots (for example, FirstService does work that involves an instance of both Aggregate1 and Aggregate2), which is why the work is done in a domain service rather than in the aggregate roots themselves.

Comment: In this case I do not see 3 copies of aggregate1

Comment: @Valerii Ok, I updated the original post with more code to try to explain where all three copies of aggregate1 are created

Comment: Now I see 3 copies. Why don't pass agregate1 and agregate2 into DoWork instead of Id's. In this case you will not have to look for this entities. What is the responsibility of FirstService and SecondService?

Comment: These services would do something like update a value inside of aggregate1 based on some values in aggregate 2 or 3.  For example, FirstService might set aggregate1.CountOfSomething equal to itself + aggregate2.CountChange.  I know that this example is too far abstracted at this point, but the idea is that these would be two separate aggregate roots that need some calculations done between them, so the calculation is handled in a domain service.

Comment: In this case maybe it would have a sense to separate calculation and update. I think if your services would do only calculation it will allow to handle updates in code inside "using" block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, your problem isn't really related to DDD. It's just a typical ORM/AutoMapper issue.

You should **NEVER** use AutoMapper to map **TO** an persistence model or a domain model, this will **almost never** work.

The reasons for this lies, that most/many ORMs will track entities and their changes via references (i.e. EntityFramework). So if you use automapper and get new instances, you break the way ORM works and run into such problems.

This may be an interesting read for you: [Why mapping DTOs to Entities using AutoMapper and EntityFramework is horrible](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/)

While it handles DTO -> Entity, it applies same to Domain Model -> Entity.

Also Jimmy Bogard (author of AutoMapper) once commented on a blog post (which is unavailable now, but the disqus comments are [still there](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/codingforfunandprofit/friends_dont_let_friends_use_automapper_andrew_harcourt_uglybuggerorg_31/))

Jimmy Bogard commented:

> There are definitely places to use AutoMapper, and places *not* to use
>   it. However, I think this post misses them:
>
> 1. Configuration
>      validation takes care of members that exist on the destination type
>      that aren't mapped. That's easy.
> 2. Dependency injection takes care of depending directly on other
>      assemblies. For example, you'd have IRepository in Core and the
>      implementation that references System.Data in another assembly
> 3. **AutoMapper was never, ever intended to map *back* into a behavioral
>      model. AutoMapper is intended to build DTOs, not map back in**
> 4. AutoMapper also uses Reflection.Emit and expression tree compilation,
>      cached once. If you use autoprojection, it's faster than any
>      server-side code you could write yourself.
>
> The points you raised are common complaints, but mostly it's people
>   not understand how to use AutoMapper correctly. However, there are
>   places I absolutely wouldn't use AutoMapper:
>
> 1. When the destination type isn't a projection of the source type.
>      Seems obvious, if AutoMapper isn't Auto then there's no point. It's
>      supposed to get rid of the brain-dead code you would be forced to
>      write anyway.
> 2. Mapping to complex models. I only use AutoMapper to
>      flatten/project, never back to behavioral models. I'm very up front
>      about this and discourage this use whenever I see it.
> 3. Anywhere that you're not trying to delete code you would have written anyway.
> 4. You prefer explicit over convention. This is a whole other topic, with
>      pros and cons of both approaches.
> 5. You prefer not to understand the
>      magic. I build lots of convention-based helpers covering a wide array
>      of scenarios, but I make sure that my team understands what is
>      actually happening underneath the covers.

Your options basically boil down to

1. Use event sourcing for your domain model (and build it as a series of events inside the repository, so for persistence you only save new models)

**OR**

2. use your domain model directly as persistence model.

The later one will cause that some persistence detail leak into your domain model. This may or may not be acceptable for your use case. It usually works well in smaller projects where Event Sourcing is out of scope.

As for the rest of your example, it's a bit to far from a practical use case and it's hard to say why your services are created that way.

Could be a bad chosen aggregate root, wrong/bad separation of concerns. Hard to tell from **abstracted** terms as `SecondService` etc.

An aggregate root can be seen as a transaction boundary. All entities within that root needs to be updated at the same time.

The fact, that you pass only ids to the `DoWork` methods indicates that they are different operations (and hence, transactions on their own) or that only the id should be assigned.

If they were supposed to be used in an outer scope you should pass in the aggregate root references to it, rather than only pass the ids.

```
firstService.DoWork(aggregate1,aggregate2); 
secondService.DoWork(aggregate1,aggregate3);

// instead of 
firstService.DoWork(aggregate1.Id,aggregate2.Id); 
secondService.DoWork(aggregate1.Id,aggregate3.Id);
```

You can't (and shouldn't) rely on the fact, that some ORMs may cache an entity, hence not rely that multiple calls to your repository will return the exact same instance of the entity.

Comment: Thanks Tseng, this helps clear up some confusion for me.  I like the simplicity of using the domain model as a persistence model, but I found many articles online saying not to do that.  I still don't know much about using domain events, so I'll look into that some more.  However, maybe using the domain model as the persistence model wouldn't be that bad in my case since it's a one-man project.

Comment: Many discourage of directly using domain model as entity/persistence model, because ORM specifics leak into your domain (i.e. requiring a protected parameterless constructor, private setters or "primary key" fields on your entities (i.e. having an `id`field on an `OrderLine`. From DDD PoV, `Id` on it is useless, but for ORM you need it if you use RDBMS, but non-existent if you use document database). Domain events are not the same as event sourcing events. Domain events allow logic to be applied on the entity on an event. Event sourcing is a history of applied changes to the aggregate model

Comment: Thank you for the correction, saved me a headache later on when I go to research it!

Comment: I think having "Id" in a domain model is fine compared to adding an additional layer to maintain. You can always make it `private`, but still, you probably will need that Id in your UI. So how will you map your domain model to your view model without having an `Id` on it?

Comment: In the worst case, you would end up with at least 3 model layers to maintain: UI models(DTO/ViewModels/Request,response models), domain models and persistence models. And the mapping code that goes after it...

Comment: @Konrad: Only if you don't understand the consequences or decide to ignore these. you may have an "orderPositionId" which is an unique (auto-increment) field. But if you ever decide to move to lets say a document database, there is no such and, since is not necessary within document databases. Or if you decide to use a plain xml file to store instead of a database.this field only exists because the persistent storage requires it. If you have that in your code and use it, then move, you are in trouble since you have to change a lot of your domain code because persistance changed

Comment: And this misses the point of using DDD in the first place. You essentially trade faster development time vs maintenance nightmare later on and all you reach with it that your technical debt grows. Ideally one uses CQRS and event sourcing, then all the object-relational impedance mismatch is a non-issue in the first place, because your domain entities then get their state by replaying events

Comment: @Tseng but there always need to be something that uniquely identifies your domain model, so you can pass that down to the underlying database.

Comment: because let's say you have `OrderItem` if you won't put some `Id` in your domain model how will you refer to that order item? how will it communicate with the persistence layer?

Comment: @Konrad: That's a concern of the persistence layer. It has to decide how to handle it. When its a document db, you don't even have to worry, since only the document has references (which can be the order number rather than some auto increment id). For relational DBs, the ORM can do the work and handling the ID transparently (i.e. in EF Core you could define an entity whose relation database key is a shadow property, which is not defined on the model itself and its relationship is referenced though the parent entity).

Comment: The moment you start to add database specific into your domain, you have lost the race and your persistence (=infrastructure) leaks into your domain and your domain has dependency on external system which is something you want to avoid in DDD. Only other layers can have dependency on the domain layer and domain layer shouldn't/must not have dependencies on infrastructure. Its not easy for DDD beginners to understand that and they just walk into that trap. Like I said, using CQRS+ES and you don't need any db specific properties. But CQRS+ES adds additional complexity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177815/discussion-between-tseng-and-konrad).

Comment: @Tseng https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235254/id-properties-on-domain-objects-in-ddd

Comment: "When a relational DB is used, not adding a technical Id will lead to the usage of domain keys as foreign keys. So in this case, every table referencing the Account table will store a duplicate of the "sort number" and the "account number". Now imagine what will happen if some domain requirements change (like local country bank account numbers to be replaced by IBAN, as its currently happening in Europe)."